# What's the best way to get a number as input from python while maintaining type

Tags: python, shell, input, command-line-interface

I'm trying to get a number as CLI input from python. Valid input should be either an int or a float and I need to maintain type. So validating an int and returning a float wouldn't work.

This is the best thing I've been able to come up with and it's not all that good.

```
def is_valid(n):
    try:
        if '.' in n: return float(n)
        return int(n)
    except ValueError:
        print "try again"

def num_input(s):
    n = raw_input(s)
    while is_valid(n) is None:
        n = raw_input(s)
    return is_valid(n)

valid_num = num_input("Enter a valid number: ")
```

Clearly this isn't the best way.

Comment: While you will probably receive several suggestions about how to tweak this code and make it slightly more Pythonic, I actually think the approach is sound — I am not sure why it is clear to you that this is not, in fact, roughly the best way. :)

Comment: This wont work for "1e3" for example. `float("1e3")` works, but `int("1e3")` doesn't

Comment: @Brandon - b/c it's a lot of _python_ code to get something so simple done and checking for the dot just felt wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considering the early answers and thinking about it a bit more the solution I came up with is:

```
def num_input(prompt, error):
    s = raw_input(prompt)
    for t in (int, float, complex):
        try: return t(s)
        except ValueError: pass
    print error
    return num_input(prompt, error) #better get it in the first 1k tries
```

I really want an input function not just a validation function; however, I think [HYRY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342103/whats-the-best-way-to-get-a-number-as-input-from-python-while-maintaining-type/7342240#7342240)'s suggestion to loop over int, float, complex is a good one. I took [win](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342103/whats-the-best-way-to-get-a-number-as-input-from-python-while-maintaining-type/7342362#7342362)'s suggestion to use recursion instead of looping, understanding that a really confused and persistent user could exceed the max recursion depth. Although I don't need it now, I think [Karl Knechtel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342103/whats-the-best-way-to-get-a-number-as-input-from-python-while-maintaining-type/7342792#7342792) is correct in making the error an arg instead of hard coded.

Answer (score 8):

use a for loop to try all the conversions, I added complex type for demonstration:

```
def is_valid(n):
    for t in (int, float, complex):
        try:
            return t(n)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError("invalid number %s" % n)

print is_valid("10")
print is_valid("10.0")
print is_valid("1+3.0j")
```

Comment: this would always return, say, 1.2 as an int !

Comment: int("1.2") raise ValueError, int(1.2) return 1. in this case, n is a string input by raw_input.

Comment: oh, excuse me. you're correct.  it's an awkward interface though, i would expect a function called `is_valid` to return a bool, not the converted number itself.  and i would not usually expect an argument called `n` to be a string.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; however, looping over the types in an order seems reasonable, to the point of obvious correctness. Is the idea of stacking types in order like this something fundamental in CS/Math type systems / number theory?

Answer (score 1):

```
def num_input(prompt, error):
    while True:
        result = raw_input(prompt)
        for candidate in (int, float):
            try: return candidate(result)
            except ValueError: pass
        print error
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the decimal module which will allow you to maintain exactly the precision of the entered number eg:

```
import decimal

def num_input(s):
    while True:
        try:
            return decimal.Decimal(raw_input(s))
        except decimal.InvalidOperation, e:
            print e.message


valid_num = num_input("Enter a decimal number: ")

print 'ANSWER: ', valid_num
```

See: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html